# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called when creating a scatter plot

Tags: pandas, numpy, plot, plotly, plotly-python

For each gene, I want to plot the effect of time (x-axis) on the gene expression (y-axis).

My code raised `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` error.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for time, gene_expr in df5.iloc[:, 1:-1].iterrows():
  X = time
  y = gene_expr

  fig = px.scatter(X, y)
  fig.show()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-424-e9af712893e6> in <module>()
      4   y = gene_expr
      5 
----> 6   fig = px.scatter(X, y)
      7   fig.show()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in scatter(data_frame, x, y, color, symbol, size, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, facet_row_spacing, facet_col_spacing, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, orientation, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, symbol_sequence, symbol_map, opacity, size_max, marginal_x, marginal_y, trendline, trendline_options, trendline_color_override, trendline_scope, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
     64     mark in 2D space.
     65     """
---> 66     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
     67 
     68 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1943     apply_default_cascade(args)
   1944 
-> 1945     args = build_dataframe(args, constructor)
   1946     if constructor in [go.Treemap, go.Sunburst, go.Icicle] and args["path"] is not None:
   1947         args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in build_dataframe(args, constructor)
   1304     df_provided = args["data_frame"] is not None
   1305     if df_provided and not isinstance(args["data_frame"], pd.DataFrame):
-> 1306         args["data_frame"] = pd.DataFrame(args["data_frame"])
   1307     df_input = args["data_frame"]
   1308 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    728         else:
    729             if index is None or columns is None:
--> 730                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
    731 
    732             # Argument 1 to "ensure_index" has incompatible type "Collection[Any]";

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Data:

```
df5.head().to_dict()

{'DNAJA1': {'0': 0.28248390645176796,
  '12': 0.27744322221439516,
  '24': 0.210254923999168,
  '4': 0.25179129535390465,
  '8': 0.23958153803449567},
 'DNAJA1P5': {'0': -0.2080266957602313,
  '12': -0.19722801757776928,
  '24': -0.1976431590905783,
  '4': -0.20053252198361712,
  '8': -0.2036891696122125},
 'DNAJA2': {'0': 0.2379156190731321,
  '12': 0.23129783609535023,
  '24': 0.20515225879608529,
  '4': 0.21167004692557853,
  '8': 0.22217035173976502},
 'DNAJA3': {'0': 0.14072466843555423,
  '12': 0.12502300219684245,
  '24': 0.14012001787306544,
  '4': 0.1526473568816046,
  '8': 0.12756243532358302},
 'DNAJA4': {'0': 0.29363403599517873,
  '12': 0.2199610571535649,
  '24': 0.21450642787801127,
  '4': 0.2863189438304104,
  '8': 0.22237180092783923},
 'DNAJB1': {'0': 0.3948121317283425,
  '12': 0.3608993750139941,
  '24': 0.3311254737056284,
  '4': 0.3981327559482513,
  '8': 0.3319362201574015},
 'DNAJB11': {'0': 0.2746271580199511,
  '12': 0.23630738713618987,
  '24': 0.22299890869123462,
  '4': 0.24300028615442973,
  '8': 0.2382232952434325},
 'DNAJB12': {'0': 0.10668014577426282,
  '12': 0.11955750186231344,
  '24': 0.12738441668520886,
  '4': 0.12070656206120234,
  '8': 0.11469633018832656},
 'DNAJB13': {'0': -0.07673116489135769,
  '12': -0.06776710496304854,
  '24': -0.07153667570066105,
  '4': -0.06691126916859379,
  '8': -0.07310350056725066},
 'DNAJB14': {'0': 0.2936152967643217,
  '12': 0.30721637266817337,
  '24': 0.2752172143325089,
  '4': 0.28537539621170677,
  '8': 0.2847856843270891},
 'DNAJB2': {'0': 0.1581524535439132,
  '12': 0.15176006759808186,
  '24': 0.14005726324108353,
  '4': 0.16744525625230677,
  '8': 0.14085238694516192},
 'DNAJB3': {'0': -0.09587483337552667,
  '12': -0.09817644148708737,
  '24': -0.09660994242851631,
  '4': -0.08518473151331872,
  '8': -0.10146894931303332},
 'DNAJB4': {'0': 0.07768482492238449,
  '12': 0.017092721241614726,
  '24': -0.01615829598116708,
  '4': 0.020593555517848337,
  '8': -0.004092727323577966},
 'DNAJB5': {'0': 0.09496018939632274,
  '12': 0.09235963667312883,
  '24': 0.10859047142465117,
  '4': 0.11145101928004025,
  '8': 0.09014175789905482},
 'DNAJB6 /// TMEM135': {'0': 0.30131649339447103,
  '12': 0.28354614480145346,
  '24': 0.27395808285292367,
  '4': 0.2949284643966144,
  '8': 0.2794865791356734},
 'DNAJB7': {'0': -0.15771205782877812,
  '12': -0.14511310398241917,
  '24': -0.1555102987841566,
  '4': -0.1443977313282421,
  '8': -0.15281879296022327},
 'DNAJB8': {'0': -0.05820495004065927,
  '12': -0.04784161289502813,
  '24': -0.049103502142104925,
  '4': -0.049599985194195624,
  '8': -0.06345844493362643},
 'DNAJB9': {'0': 0.11076998890482295,
  '12': 0.06169995333733465,
  '24': 0.05327189778896728,
  '4': 0.07866774006161506,
  '8': 0.054673294559794514},
 'DNAJC1': {'0': 0.24892722200000175,
  '12': 0.24941676796653142,
  '24': 0.24834878985541864,
  '4': 0.23839909816627536,
  '8': 0.2457747521222172},
 'DNAJC10': {'0': 0.2552488374526568,
  '12': 0.23718885573814158,
  '24': 0.219399461349515,
  '4': 0.25279546962976474,
  '8': 0.2313752090822519},
 'DNAJC11': {'0': 0.10008360015453403,
  '12': 0.09051095629609844,
  '24': 0.08314056952230306,
  '4': 0.10190650783898647,
  '8': 0.08229407961363017},
 'DNAJC12': {'0': -0.12299257208661085,
  '12': -0.1141270169596548,
  '24': -0.13300032732527073,
  '4': -0.13215534856752542,
  '8': -0.1269886655735006},
 'DNAJC13': {'0': 0.4009152082570292,
  '12': 0.43945616890620476,
  '24': 0.406718584282217,
  '4': 0.4051887086934543,
  '8': 0.4207699468459298},
 'DNAJC14': {'0': 0.2255444383216058,
  '12': 0.2343653660720247,
  '24': 0.2246018336027369,
  '4': 0.22905481299223704,
  '8': 0.22228815371920396},
 'DNAJC15': {'0': 0.25789169794229455,
  '12': 0.2406210529534205,
  '24': 0.22347959865906092,
  '4': 0.22312009403152122,
  '8': 0.22912018863353348},
 'DNAJC16': {'0': 0.25118250606032994,
  '12': 0.2634603140695134,
  '24': 0.2559437693580005,
  '4': 0.260663050530101,
  '8': 0.25672778315798805},
 'DNAJC17': {'0': 0.0718240184764887,
  '12': 0.08705114604826444,
  '24': 0.07478605493065499,
  '4': 0.0867030049108327,
  '8': 0.07226672139164557},
 'DNAJC18': {'0': 0.05301961450370261,
  '12': 0.04754701545460298,
  '24': 0.04744710465261325,
  '4': 0.058410734627379245,
  '8': 0.04612151982443032},
 'DNAJC19': {'0': -0.061318907045887217,
  '12': -0.06522383392518652,
  '24': -0.07428845844165784,
  '4': -0.07689535420225665,
  '8': -0.07132412412619679},
 'DNAJC2': {'0': 0.12354944077460604,
  '12': 0.10590867281952658,
  '24': 0.08647106591019343,
  '4': 0.11280280873592663,
  '8': 0.09861702152191035},
 'DNAJC21': {'0': 0.18568509930510457,
  '12': 0.16206451389465568,
  '24': 0.13974449617707058,
  '4': 0.1642464451002627,
  '8': 0.1601371719124281},
 'DNAJC22': {'0': -0.09326088886326482,
  '12': -0.09994315166353215,
  '24': -0.09818616566701992,
  '4': -0.0766139542789032,
  '8': -0.09474493076293106},
 'DNAJC24': {'0': -0.024407871322284516,
  '12': -0.04388395219646757,
  '24': -0.030418881816888975,
  '4': -0.03884605873284513,
  '8': -0.04057519700577427},
 'DNAJC25 /// DNAJC25-GNG10 /// GNG10': {'0': 0.18900015728770594,
  '12': 0.1924709267155032,
  '24': 0.1855722328342354,
  '4': 0.18293809001992412,
  '8': 0.17782253125321112},
 'DNAJC27': {'0': 0.031979181807859955,
  '12': 0.031014849632422552,
  '24': 0.03738291752852443,
  '4': 0.05264384837943797,
  '8': 0.01639331282320123},
 'DNAJC28': {'0': -0.10603389682143655,
  '12': -0.10738830197430897,
  '24': -0.11228995887813542,
  '4': -0.1091487503462486,
  '8': -0.12087183521953099},
 'DNAJC3': {'0': 0.30260069114488775,
  '12': 0.3250607363561909,
  '24': 0.296968150791487,
  '4': 0.2999460613167164,
  '8': 0.3223833673779394},
 'DNAJC30': {'0': 0.11388797858763917,
  '12': 0.11229754447748205,
  '24': 0.11379897713291527,
  '4': 0.13114878202076288,
  '8': 0.11799998627920205},
 'DNAJC4 /// NUDT22': {'0': 0.24319510455934645,
  '12': 0.27248047790015295,
  '24': 0.2758415067986132,
  '4': 0.2617636798697484,
  '8': 0.2612483452622727},
 'DNAJC5': {'0': 0.29256319288876087,
  '12': 0.3284481866393536,
  '24': 0.3097473292260611,
  '4': 0.2991498817082909,
  '8': 0.3118310482972686},
 'DNAJC5B': {'0': -0.16513673294958436,
  '12': -0.14577354129936956,
  '24': -0.16602256134508964,
  '4': -0.15831273634383858,
  '8': -0.14704570894539276},
 'DNAJC5G': {'0': -0.12154026872582889,
  '12': -0.10829345557004925,
  '24': -0.1128175514728689,
  '4': -0.12706121166279596,
  '8': -0.11547448664939705},
 'DNAJC6': {'0': 0.013532483149184604,
  '12': 0.016620550092782228,
  '24': 0.011437913693540098,
  '4': 0.015691143400912946,
  '8': 0.011508823424590173},
 'DNAJC7': {'0': 0.21805318734860135,
  '12': 0.21928981693914756,
  '24': 0.19266797382682654,
  '4': 0.20586403937384182,
  '8': 0.20525988410009127},
 'DNAJC8': {'0': 0.1333821893656816,
  '12': 0.14559322801116542,
  '24': 0.10962743627286925,
  '4': 0.1263955617218009,
  '8': 0.11561971140994581},
 'DNAJC9': {'0': 0.11205541676885071,
  '12': 0.12045170255898871,
  '24': 0.10622530623273815,
  '4': 0.12991396178392187,
  '8': 0.10520854728987451},
 'LOC646358': {'0': 0.2368501920161727,
  '12': 0.23935130874144087,
  '24': 0.1927312962920997,
  '4': 0.2082556333663144,
  '8': 0.24129365615652498},
 'ST13': {'0': 0.3904955795353276,
  '12': 0.3429657340591041,
  '24': 0.35263630061055307,
  '4': 0.3832450736771604,
  '8': 0.36547818653640995},
 'ST13P4': {'0': 0.2125373177633469,
  '12': 0.1844503555760748,
  '24': 0.1844713371907022,
  '4': 0.20655218905005068,
  '8': 0.20207292104855787},
 'ST13P5': {'0': 0.2388445698279386,
  '12': 0.202381644929025,
  '24': 0.20119515611287567,
  '4': 0.22513288946386512,
  '8': 0.223608506831124},
 'VEGFA': {'0': 0.19732697850691847,
  '12': 0.176210462112851,
  '24': 0.17134417427533616,
  '4': 0.17708075993852013,
  '8': 0.16899091572086322},
 'VEGFB': {'0': 0.1424721668873727,
  '12': 0.13628100283545955,
  '24': 0.14628256064354891,
  '4': 0.17019608917147688,
  '8': 0.13664990684590392},
 'VEGFC': {'0': 0.0094810175674546,
  '12': 0.021314980865977315,
  '24': 0.027110162884579722,
  '4': 0.016743433302740356,
  '8': 0.006834653321976023},
 'survival_info': {'0': '0h', '12': '12h', '24': '24h', '4': '4h', '8': '8h'}}
```

Versions:

Python 3.7.13
plotly 5.9.0
Pandas 1.3.5

Comment: your code is working for me. pandas - 1.4.2 and plotly - 4.12.0

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.13, Pandas 1.3.5, and plotly 5.9.0

Comment: Since `iterrows()` of a data frame iteration returns indexes and rows, in this case the x-axis is the column name and the y-axis is the value, resulting in the following code. `for time, gene_expr in df5.iloc[:, 1:-1].iterrows():    X = df5.iloc[:, 1:-1].columns.tolist();   
    y = gene_expr.tolist();    fig = px.scatter(x=X, y=y);    fig.show()`

Answer (score 0):

As @r-beginners wrote, pd.Dataframe.iterrows() returns a tuple `(row_index, row)`. In your code index was stored in X variable, so it was just an integer, which caused an error.

I adapted you code to get row info from iterrows:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for i, row in df5[:, 1:-1].iterrows():
    row = dict(row)
    X = list(row.keys())
    y = list(row.values())

    fig = px.scatter(X, y)
    fig.show()
```

I am not sure, if you really want 5 separate scatter plots printed out, though?